# Remove first option from the select 2 dropdown while onchange the dropdown

Tags: plugins, jquery-select2

I have a select2 dropdown box below,

```
<select class="select_drop wid_100" id="dropDownId">
    <option value="">Select Account Manager</option>
    <option value="1">Brown</option>
    <option value="2">Isacc</option>
</select>
```

OnChange of the dropdown I have to change the drop down default text to "Change Account Manager" and the option "Select Account Manager" has to remove. Tried below script.

```
<script>
    $('#dropDownId').change(function() {        
        $("#select2-chosen-1").text("Change Account Manager");
        $("#dropDownId option[value='option1']").remove();                                                
    });
<script>
```

The text change to "Change Account Manager", but the first option not removing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Change
$('#dropDownId').change(function() {        
    $("#select2-chosen-1").text("Change Account Manager");
    $("#dropDownId option[value='option1']").remove();                                                
});

To 
$('#dropDownId').change(function() {        
    $("#select2-chosen-1").text("Change Account Manager");
    $("#dropDownId option[value='1']").remove();                                                
});

 The Value is 1, not option1
```

Comment: Can I add back the option value into another event, something like this $("#dropDownId option[value='0']").add();

Comment: as a first option index

Comment: You bet, $('#dropDownId').append($('<option>', { value: 1, text: 'Brown' }));